# 120v to 24v 40va transformer damaged, replaced with 120v to 24v 15va transformer

Tags: power, transformer

Powermaster J51 electric gate motor tested, working. Problem is that remote relay does not engage despite new transformer. If the relay is helped (manual push) it will engage and remain engaged until the end of the cycle. Could the change in the rating of the transformer from 40VA to 15VA be the reason?
The original transformer was damaged by hurricane Maria. Only replacement found was the 15 VA one.

Comment: the relay in question is the final bridge that connects 120v to motor forward or reverse mode

Comment: Usually, when a relay doesn't quite engage correctly, it's about the driving voltage being insufficient. For example, using a 24 volt coil voltage relay used where an 18 volt coil voltage one is supposed to be used. I think you are talking about the switching contacts, though. Maybe? Could you provide more information about the system, what you were supposed to get but couldn't find, and what you actually used? It might help someone identify the specifics for you. Part #s and manufacturers would be wonderful, if possible.

Comment: Sounds like wrong coil voltage indeed. Datasheet of the relay? Unless you can provide more info this repair question is unfortunately off-topic.

Comment: The secondary coil resistance of the 15 VA transformer might be too large for the current necessary to drive the remote relay. A 40 VA transformer will have a smaller resistance and is able to deliver the needed current.

Comment: A 40VA transformer will be more expensive than a15VA one so it is unlikely the designer would specify 40VA if 15VA would do.  We would need more details of the circuit to be sure though.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you actually measure the current required by the system when fed with a suffiently-large transformer, you won't know if the smaller transformer will work reliably.

Based on your description, I would suggest that the replacement transformer at 15VA is far too small and you really do need to obtain a 40VA transformer.

If you are having problems finding a suitable transformer, why not visit your friendly neighbourhood HVAC company.  24 Vac transformers are standard in HVAC systems and every furnace / air conditioning shop that I have ever dealt with stocks 24 Vac transformers in various sizes.